# Showing loading spinner on other thread

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, grand-central-dispatch, uiactivityindicatorview

I am kinda new on iOS native development. I am loading info from an API call, and while loading I want to show the "loading spinner".

Everything works, but I get this warning on the Log:
" Obtaining the web lock from a thread other than the main thread or the web thread. UIKit should not be called from a secondary thread. "

This is my code:

```
UIActivityIndicatorView *spinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
spinner.center = CGPointMake(160, 150);
spinner.hidesWhenStopped = YES;
[self.view addSubview:spinner];
[spinner startAnimating];
[UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;

dispatch_queue_t downloadQueue = dispatch_queue_create("downloader", NULL);



dispatch_async(downloadQueue, ^{
    NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://www.***********?q=%@",[self.searchBar.text urlEncode:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    NSURL *googleURL = [NSURL URLWithString:url];
    NSData *jsonData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:googleURL];

    NSError *error = nil;
    NSDictionary *dataDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:0 error:&error];
    for (NSDictionary *items in [dataDict objectForKey:@"items"]) {
        Book *book = [Book bookWithTitle:[[items objectForKey:@"volumeInfo"] objectForKey:@"title"]];
        book.authors = [[[items objectForKey:@"volumeInfo"] objectForKey:@"authors"] objectAtIndex:(0)];

        [self.rowsInSection addObject:book];

    }



    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [spinner stopAnimating];
        [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
        [[self myTableView]reloadData];
        [self.view endEditing:YES];
    });

});
```

I have tried to switch the two threads but that didn't work.
Any idea?

Thanks!
A.

EDIT:

I solved the warning. Basically it was happening because I was accessing the "self.searchBar.text" inside the other thread. To solve this I used a local variable to store it and then use that variable in the thread.
It's still a bit confusing for me, but at least I have no errors or warnings.

Thanks to everyone for the comments/answers and help!

A.

Comment: The warning shouldn't be taken too lightly, but chances are it'll never be a real issue. If you're concerned about it you can always use a NSAutoReleasePool and NSThread.

Comment: Thanks! I'll have a look at those.

Comment: What's `self.rowsInSection`?

Comment: which call is giving you the warning? and are you making the call to this method on a secondary thread?

Comment: @MarcusAdams roewsInSection is a property I use for a tableView, to set the number of rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this warning happen to me and it was because I was changing spinner attributes INSIDE the block as you are.

I fixed it by moving any "spinner" calls outside the block. I just created a method to stop the spinner. Something like:

```
__weak YourClass blockSelf = self;
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [blockSelf spinnerStop:spinner]; //REPLACED THIS LINE
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
    [[blockSelf myTableView]reloadData];
    [blockSelf endEditing:YES];
});
```

Method

```
-(void)spinnerStop:(UIActivityIndicatorView *)activityView {
    [activityView stopAnimating];
    [activityView removeFromSubView];
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this, it didn't solve my warning but it's another nice way to do it. After all I'm still learning.